# How do I decode a msgpack file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, msgpack

I've created a msgpack file from a Pandas Dataframe, using the following code:

```
df.to_msgpack('ixto.msg')
```

I've confirmed that the file is saved in the directory, but I can't use msgpack library for python since the following code:

```
unp = msgpack.unpackb('ixto.msg')
```

gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: is this a typo? you're missing a trailing quotation mark: `unp = msgpack.unpackb('ixto.msg')`

Comment: yes, it is. now is correct

Comment: See also: [How do I read and write with msgpack?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43442194/562769)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`msgpack.unpackb` expects bytes (thus the "b") containing encoded data, and you're giving it the name of the file containing the data.

So you need to read the file first :

```
with open('ixto.msg', 'rb') as f:
    unp = msgpack.unpackb(f.read())
```