# How do I read and write with msgpack?

Tags: python, msgpack

How do I serialize / deserialize a dictionary `data` with [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [Python docs](http://msgpack-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest) seem not to be so good, so here is my try.

### Installation

```
pip install msgpack
```

### Read and Write msgpack

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import msgpack

# Define data
data = {
    "a list": [1, 42, 3.141, 1337, "help"],
    "a string": "bla",
    "another dict": {"foo": "bar", "key": "value", "the answer": 42},
}

# Write msgpack file
with open("data.msgpack", "wb") as outfile:
    packed = msgpack.packb(data)
    outfile.write(packed)

# Read msgpack file
with open("data.msgpack", "rb") as data_file:
    byte_data = data_file.read()

data_loaded = msgpack.unpackb(byte_data)
print(data == data_loaded)
```

### Alternatives

- CSV: Super simple format ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585079/562769))
- JSON: Nice for writing human-readable data; VERY commonly used ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795053/562769))
- YAML: YAML is a superset of JSON, but easier to read ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42054860/562769), [comparison of JSON and YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729545/562769))
- pickle: A Python serialization format ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33245595/562769))
- [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) ([Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python)): More compact representation ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43442194/562769))
- [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) ([Python package](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html)): Nice for matrices ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41586571/562769))
- XML: exists too *sigh* ([read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912483/562769) & [write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605831/562769))

For your application, the following might be important:

- Support by other programming languages
- Reading / writing performance
- Compactness (file size)

See also: [Comparison of data serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats)

In case you are rather looking for a way to make configuration files, you might want to read my short article [Configuration files in Python](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/)

Comment: We now only use pip install msgpack. msgpack-python is outdated, as per pypi.

Comment: What is the recommended extension for msgpack file?

Comment: Well, I would recommend `msgpack`. But I'm also not aware of any other Python packages that support msgpack.

Comment: msgpack._packer.Packer._pack
TypeError: can't serialize 1.0

Comment: For me when using more recent versions of python a `rb` flag has to be added to the file open function (I have read, not sure about writing).

Comment: Getting error `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`. I am on Py3.7

Comment: @Volatil3 Thank you for letting me know. I'm not sure why, but the code didn't work anymore. I've updated the example.

Comment: what if i dont have the data and i need to paste the jiberish from redis to the load, who to do this?

Comment: are the msgpack in your answer and the MessagePack in the "alternatives" the same?