# How to pack arrays iwht msgpack on python?

Tags: python, arrays, save

I have a `dict` of arrays like these:

`gen = {0: [array([0])], 1: [array([1]), array([-1])]}`

and I would like to save them with `msgpack`:

```
import msgpack

with open('data.msgpack', 'wb') as file:
    msgpack.pack(gen, file)
```

But it returns the error:

> TypeError: can't serialize array([0])

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i do not have the reputation to comment, but you don't need to initialize an array using 'array', Just using [ ] is enough.

Said that, you can see a similar code posted by a user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43442195/4792892)

Comment: I actually need to save an array with the first entry 0.
Also, I'm doing the same thing as the code you linked to, but I do not have a list of strings, but a list of arrays

Comment: just use _gen = {0: [ [0] ], 1: [ [1], [-1] ] }_

Comment: Yeah but I need them to be arrays

Comment: Can I not save arrays at all with msgpack?